# To merge instead of replace in $zip->extractTo

Tags: php

I have used the following code to unzip a zip folder after upload.

```
  /* here it is really happening */

    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $targetzip)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $x = $zip->open($targetzip);  // open the zip file to extract
        if ($x === true) {
            echo $targetdir; exit;
            $zip->extractTo($targetdir); // place in the directory with same name  
            $zip->close();
            unlink($targetzip);
        }
        $message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
    } else {    
        $message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
    }
```

It is working fine. But the only problem is the that the folder is replaced by the new one uploaded. I want to merge it.

Suppose i have a zip folder.
One.zip
 a
 b
 c

When i upload this, it should merge with the (One) folder which is already in the upload server. So the previous folders in the (One) folder should not be replaced.

I think It is understandable now. Please help to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can con-cat current time & date with you target fine name:

```
$targetdir = $targetdir."_".str_replace(' ',"/",date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Using this logic, you fine will not replace with previous file.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But this is not what i am looking.